# ASP.NET Core 5 MVC : HTTP POST request to handle query string parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, postman, http-post, webhooks, querystringparameter

I have been tasked with writing Http `POST` method to process incoming webhook data and I have been able to achieve that but to actually start receiving I have to first subscribe to Webhook event by validating the url and for that I also have to capture query string parameter passed in `POST` request which is where I am having issues.

Below method signature is able to capture header and body and then implementation processes the data.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Callback([FromHeader(Name = "headerSignature")] string signature, [FromBody] WebHookEventData eventData)
```

However I also need to enable this to capture data coming from query string. For example below is the url with query string and when I pass that as `POST` request from Postman it throws error 415 unsupported media type:

https://webhoook.example.com/webhook/callback?centre.challenge=test

[image]

How do I capture query parameter in `POST` request?

Answer (score 0):

Simple you can use HttpContext like this:

```
var queryString = HttpContext.Request.QueryString ;
```

and if you like to Address a special QueryString do it this way :

```
var queryStringId = HttpContext.Request.Query["id"] ;
```

Hope it helps ;)